# Mongoid class with embedded_in and belongs_to entries

Tags: ruby, class, mongoid

I am creating a Mongoid based application which will have a Class (called Question) whose Objects are stored in two different ways for different purposes. One group of those objects need to be stored in an N:N relationship with Class Page and another group of the same objects need to be stored as embedded (1:N) entries in a different Class (FilledPage).

I need to be able to copy a Question Object which has been referenced in a Page into a FilledPage and for the purposes of speed, I need that to be an embedded relationship.

I have tried creating a Superclass with the information and then two child classes, but I can't convert from one child class to the other without considerable work (and this same design needs to be used in a few other areas with much greater complexity).

Is there any way to support both embedding and references in the same class, or some other solution which will do similar.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing block to have same class to be embedded or standalone. with reference. The limitation is about linking a master document to embedded document. It's not possible easily with mongodb, because your need get the master document and extract the embedded one.